# QuickTime .mov file requires quicktime 7?

Tags: video, quicktime

I have these old .mov files in my computer. When I try to open them, quicktime message pops up and says I need QuickTime version 7 top open them. (I currently have the latest version 10.something). Funny enough, the popup gives the option to install version 7, and then fails because version 7 is not available for download.

1. Why do I need version 7?
2. Any way to convert these files to newer version?

Ps: These .mov files are not standard movies, where you just press play. It's actually a 360 files, used to create "3d" environments. I am not sure how these files were made, and if it's something created with quicktime. But I would like to be able to use these files again. Any ideas?

Quicktime is a pain to work with on websites, I would be probably resorting to some other JS player, or some other 360 web viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name for these types of files is **[QuickTime VR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_VR)**. With this name you can search for applications to help open and convert the format.

FreePV is an open source project for Linux and Windows that claims to view QuickTime VR files:

> ### [FreePV - Opensource panorama viewer](http://freepv.sourceforge.net)
>
> FreePV is a viewer for QuickTime (QTVR), SPiV, cylindrical, cubic and cylindrical panoramas. The package provides a standalone panorama viewer and a Firefox/Mozilla plugin.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the name of the file @Graham. I will test the converter you linked and search for others.